# Go Testing define custom structure

Tags: go, terraform

I've followed the structure in a `tf` file, can you help me to create a proper `structure`, as I'm new to Go.

Here is `tf`

```
   ipv4    = { 
      cidrblock = "10.0.0.0/16"
      secondary = [
            {
               cidrs     = "20.0.0.0/16"
               enabled   = true
            },
            {
               cidrs     = "30.0.0.0/16"
               enabled   = true
            }
      ]
```

}

So I've an object of strings, as well a list of objects in the main object. I could make a primitive type, for example:

```
type ipv4 struct {
   cidrblock string
   cidrs     string
   enabled   bool
}

type ipv6 struct {
   border    string
   generate  bool
}

type Sets struct {
   Name      string
   IPv4      *ipv4
   IPv6      *ipv6
   Tags      map[string]string
   Tenancy   string
}
```

But I would really like to have a complex structure

Comment: what do you mean with complex interface?

Comment: I mean I would like to have something like; list>map>list>map. Basically I would like to have 1 single interface

Comment: unfortunately, you can't do that with struct. you should break it down by defining structs

Comment: are you working on creating some terraform provider? may be this can help: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/writing-custom-terraform-providers

Comment: No, I'm not creating own provider, I need to write a test to module, however, as I've mentioned, I can't make structure, maybe you can give an example how can I achieve it, by breaking down the struct?

Comment: Possibly asking the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879471/difference-between-variables-passed-in-terraform-options-for-terratest-and-terra/71884184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
type ipv4 struct {
    cidrblock string
    secondary []ipv4secondary
}

type ipv4secondary struct {
    cidrblock string
    enabled   bool
}
```

and use it as this:

```
example := ipv4{
    cidrblock: "10.0.0.0/16",
    secondary: []ipv4secondary{
        ipv4secondary{cidrblock: "20.0.0.0/16", enabled: true},
        ipv4secondary{cidrblock: "30.0.0.0/16", enabled: true},
    },
}
```

here is the example: https://go.dev/play/p/U7o0BbAis9T