# Concatenate declared variable with random string

Tags: go, terraform, terratest

It is possible, using Terratest, to declare a tfvars file with the following variable:

```
bar = {
  name   = "test"
  domain = "test.com"
  regions = [
    { location = "France Central", alias = "france" }
  ]
}
```

But include a random prefix to the bar.domain string inside the go code?

I'm using terraformOptions as follows:

```
terraformOptions := &terraform.Options{
        TerraformDir: sourcePath,
        VarFiles:     []string{variablesPath + "/integration.tfvars"},
}
```

Comment: You first need to mock the variable inputs within Terratest instead of a HCL2 variable file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879471/difference-between-variables-passed-in-terraform-options-for-terratest-and-terra/71884184 for details. Then you can use Golang to dynamically generate values. So you cannot really do this with a HCL2 variable input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not ideal for one to make use of the tfvars file directly to take the input in case of tests. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879471/difference-between-variables-passed-in-terraform-options-for-terratest-and-terra?noredirect=1&lq=1)

To answer your question :

You can use something similar to this :

```
options := terraform.Options{
        TerraformDir: "sourcePath",
        Vars: map[string]interface{}{
                "name":  "test",
                "domain": addRandomprefix()+"test.com",
                "region ":    map[string]interface{}{
                    "location" : "France Central",
                    "alias" : "france",
                },
        },
    }
```

Just create your own custom addRandomprefix() method. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Nice, thanks! I used this approach to treat only the variable that needed to have a random name, and the other variables I left on VarFiles.